# CSS Style on Grouped Table Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table that can contain a variable amount of data.
In this table, I have two columns (Month and Year) which the data us grouped by.

I am trying to alternate colors of the rows for each of the grouped datasets. For example, Everything in `Feb 2016` would have `class=a` then the next set of data `class=b`, then back to `a` etc. Essentially an odd/even but on multiple rows based on values within them.

[image]

In the image above, there would be 3 sets of data. `Feb 2016`, `June 2016`, `Jan 2017`. Top 4 rows would be `class=a`, 5&6 would be `class=b` and finally 7 would be `class=a`.

I was able to do a standard odd/even alternating row but this is a little more than that.

Here is a fiddle of the data set: https://jsfiddle.net/yo04vxoa/

Any assistance or direction would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

This is the desired result: https://jsfiddle.net/yo04vxoa/3/

Just not sure how to get those classes on the rows correctly by grouping on the similar data in month/year.

Comment: How is the HTML being generated? Are you able to add a class in the HTML? Or are you hoping for a pure CSS solution?

Comment: I am able to add anything. The table is generated via an AJAX call and I render the table based on the dataset returned. I can manipulate it in anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you are looking for:
https://jsfiddle.net/nx35pdwa/4/

```
$(data).find('requests').each(function() {
    var $p = $(this.previousElementSibling);
    if (this.previousElementSibling &&
        ($p.find('month').text() !== $(this).find('month').text() ||
         $p.find('year').text() !== $(this).find('year').text() )) {
      alt = !alt;
    }
    output += '<tr' + (alt ? ' class="alt" ' : '') + '>';
    output += '<td>' + $(this).find('month').text() + '</td>';
    output += '<td>' + $(this).find('year').text() + '</td>';
    output += '<td>' + $(this).find('title').text() + '</td>';
    output += '</tr>'
})
```

By comparing the field in the current iteration vs previous you can determine whether you need to alternate your modifier class:

Comment: I see that its working in the fiddle, just trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Code written quickly. Let me know if anything is unclear :)

Comment: It's just very different from how I am getting my data and rendering it that is causing some confusion. Here is my function: http://pastebin.com/GJQRXY1F

Comment: If you store the requests in a variable (`var requests=$(data).find('requests')`) you should be able to loop over that the same way I do over results.

Comment: @SBB I rewrote the example to come from XML rather than JSON. This should be easier to implement in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You may do something like this :

```
var flip = false;
var flipType = 'even';
$('table tbody tr').each(function(index)
{    
   var current = $('table tbody tr').eq(index).find('td').eq(2).text();
   var next = $('table tbody tr').eq(index + 1).find('td').eq(2).text();
   if(next != ""){
    if(current == next){
      if(flip)
        $(this).addClass("odd");
      else
         $(this).addClass("even");
   }
   else {
      $(this).addClass(flipType);
      flipType = "even" ? "odd" : "even";
      flip = true;
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    flipType = "odd" ? "even" : "odd";  
    $(this).addClass(flipType);
    }
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/yo04vxoa/6/

Comment: Thanks but that wasn't what I was going for. Its not an odd/even situation, its more of a grouping of rows based on a similar value within them.

Comment: @SBB: I've updated the solution and example as per need. Check if that works for you.

Comment: Both "June 2016" rows should be highlighted in this example.

Comment: Still not quite working, I added another row to your table and it didn't highlight them correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/yo04vxoa/8/

Answer (score 0):

See https://jsfiddle.net/yo04vxoa/7/

This adds classes after the table has been generated. I added a new hidden column in the table to hold the month year for each row then added the elements to an array and iterated over it to change the colour class.

new column:

```
<th style="display:none;">ColourDate</th>
```

code:

```
var myVals = [];
$(".dateColour").each(function(){
  myVals.push( { el: $(this), t: $(this).text()});
});

var lastVal = myVals[0].t;
var myClass = 'a';

$.each(myVals, function(i, e){
    if (e.t !== lastVal){
        lastVal = e.t;
        myClass = myClass == 'a'? 'b' : 'a';
    }
  e.el.parent().addClass(myClass);
});
```

Comment: I added another row to your table and It didnt switch to the green row: https://jsfiddle.net/yo04vxoa/10/

Comment: Didnt see the value in the hidden column, trying to implement it now

Comment: @SBB you added the new row as `<td style="display:none;" class="small dateColour">Jan 2017</td>`. If you change that to `<td style="display:none;" class="small dateColour">June 2017</td>` it'll work: https://jsfiddle.net/yo04vxoa/11/

Comment: Probably better to just put this logic in rendering the HTML, rather than render and add HTML to page then go traversing the DOM to apply updates later...

Comment: @TedA. True. Fiddle OP provided had the table already generated so I just worked with that.